# How can I detect the backspace key in the first position of a line with the soft keyboard?

Tags: android

I want to make a list with a checkbox for each line and be able to add and delete the lines when type enter or backspace.
The problem I have is that when I click backspace in the first position of the line, android none detects anything and I can't delete the checkbox and the line break.
Is there any way to detect the backspace key in the first position of a line with the soft keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

There is no 100% way to detect it.  But a way that will be about 95% would be to use a subclass of EditText that overrides the getInputConnection function to return your own custom InputConnection.  You will then get raw events from the soft keyboard to the InputConnection.  You can then override the deleteSurroundingText function to tell whenever any type of delete button is pressed.

Like I said this will work 95% of the time.  The remaining 5% is if the keyboard checks its cursor position and doesn't do a delete if its at the beginning of the field.  I don't know if any major keyboard does that, but its possible one does.  In that case you're SOL.